# Paste in multiple files with one command in VIM

Tags: vim, yank

Let's say i have opened 10 HTML files horizontally in VIM by using

```
vim -o *.html
```

I would like to delete the last portion of the files by using range of lines and the windo command to apply it to all windows:

```
:windo :55, $ d
```

Now, I have yanked new content and would like to paste in all files using one cmd(maybe with the help of windo again) instead of going 1 by 1 file.

What are your suggestions?

P.S. I would prefer to do it in VIM instead of using shell cmd.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:windo $pu
```

will paste your yanked text (`"` register) to each window, after the last line.